Black screen on remote desktop on Ubuntu 24.04 when the proprietary NVIDIA driver is used
I get no video when I remotely connect (using the built-in "Remote Desktop" feature) to my Ubuntu 24.04 machine (which has an RTX 3050 card) if the proprietary NVIDIA driver (no matter which one) is used. The problem disappears if I revert to the nouveau driver.

I also remember having some trouble with Remote Desktop and I ended up using AnyDesk. Why don't you give it a try?

In fact, I want to use an iPad as a second monitor, and I see no other option than Remote Desktop.
